# Java date format real simple

Tags: java, string, date

how would you write te date if i have a date and all i want is the month and the day like this (mm/dd) and then turn the month like this July, 08

Comment: What is the type of the initial date, `String` or `Date`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me see if I understood well.

You have a date like "07/08" and you want "July, 08"?

You could try [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

class Test {
    public static void main( String [] args ) throws ParseException  {

        SimpleDateFormat in  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
        SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, dd");

        System.out.println( out.format( in.parse("07/08") ) );

        // Verbose 
        //String input = "07/09";           
        //Date  date = in.parse( input );  
        //String output = out.format( date );
        //System.out.println( output );
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP wants the month & day, not year.

Answer (score 1):

The [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is your friend here. If you already have a `java.util.Date` object, just format it using the desired *pattern* (refer to the javadoc for details on date and time patterns):

```
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, dd");
String s = out.format(date); // date is your existing Date object here
```

(EDIT: I'm adding some details as the original question is unclear and I may have missed the real goal.

If you have a `String` representation of a date in a given format (e.g. MM/dd) and want to transform the representation, you'll need 2 `SimpleDateFormat` as pointed out by others: one to parse the `String` into a `Date` and another one to format the `Date`.

```
SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
Date date = in.parse(dateAsString); // dateAsString is your String representation here
```

Then use the code snippet seen above to format it.)

Comment: So why did you put Date today = new Date(); and they other guy just put 
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, dd"); 
String s = formatter.format(date);

Comment: @daddycardona: Pascal is explicitly showing that you need to provide a date datatype when using Format.format

Comment: @daddycardona I can remove it if you want :) It's just an example to show how things work, as @OMG Ponies answered.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, dd");
String s = formatter.format(date);
```

[Formatting a Date Using a Custom Format](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/FormatDate.html)

Answer (score 0):

> the month and the day like this (mm/dd) and then turn the month like this July, 08

So you want to convert `MM/dd` to `MMMM, dd`? So you start with a `String` and you end up with a `String`? Then you need another `SimpleDateFormat` instance with the first pattern.

```
String dateString1 = "07/08";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd").parse(dateString1);
String dateString2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, dd").format(date);
System.out.println(dateString2); // July, 08 (monthname depends on locale!).
```