# Formatting date 2/24 as "February, 24"

Tags: java, format

I am trying t make a date that comes in like this mm/dd turn into the name of the month and day like it comes in 8/15 i want it to say August, 15

```
public void printAlphabetical()
{
           int month,day;// i got the month and day from a user previously in my program

       String s = String.format("%B, %02d%n",month,day);
       Date date = new Date();
       date.parse(s);// this does not work
       System.out.printf(s);
}
```

Comment: it's spelled February ;)

Comment: also you might wish to expand on where you're actually having a problem. p.s. this sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: this is a homework assignment and so i spelled it wrong you know what I meant lol anyways I have been at this all day yesterday and so far since like 7 am

Comment: Dude, you asked that question twice yesterday and there is dozen of answers already on SO. Did you consider trying to understand the answers already given before to post a new question? You are only generating noise here...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800091/java-date-format-real-simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] months = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
                    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}

System.out.println(months[month - 1] + ", " + day);
```

Comment: He want full month names and you're leaving the SimpleDateFormat capabilities aside.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. Much better would be using a date-time library.

Answer (score 2):

```
    System.out.println( new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, dd").format( 
                          new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd").parse("2/24") ) );
```

mmhh dejavu? nahhh exact duplicate -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800091/java-date-format-real-simple/1800260#1800260)

Comment: As I interpret it, he rather wanted `d` instead of `dd`.

Comment: Yeah, it is a mystery. It works the same anyway.  Parsing 2/24 yields february, 24.

Comment: Yes, but formatting using `d` yields February, 1 and formatting using `dd` yields February, 01.

Answer (score 1):

See [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Java simple date format:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateStr + "/2000); // Must use leap year
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, dd");
            System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Comment: Sorry. I have the month and day reversed. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

> 2/24 as “February, 24”

So, the starting date has a pattern of `M/d` and the final date has a pattern of `MMMM, d`?

Use [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) wisely. First parse the `String` based on the desired pattern into a `Date` and then `format` the obtained `Date` into another `String` with the desired pattern.

Basic example:

```
String datestring1 = "2/24"; // or = month + "/" + day;
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d").parse(datestring1);
String datestring2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, d").format(date);
System.out.println(datestring2); // February, 24 (Month name is locale dependent!)
```

Comment: What about linking directly to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800091/java-date-format-real-simple/1800202#1800202?

Comment: That's just a compilation error. The posted code compiles fine. Maybe you imported `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`. That's often the first class with which an IDE pops up and also often which causes problems among the unawareness.

Comment: @Pascal: although the concepts are the same, but that's a different answer.